# Converting a python series object to a pd.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, object

Looking for some help. I have a object that I am trying to convert to a pd.DataFrame.

The data is structured the following way:

````
1      {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
2      {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
3      {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
4      {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
                             ...                        
153    {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
154    {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
155    {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
156    {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
157    {'count': 0, 'distances': {'values': [], 'unit...
Name: people, Length: 158, dtype: object>"```

What I am trying to do is convert the tuple of 'count' and the associated value into the Data Frame.

Have not had much luck searching for solutions so anything help would be appreciated.
````

Comment: Please share the input in a form we can use ourselves to instantiate the Series and show the desired output DataFrame.

Comment: Take a look at `json_normalize`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Corralien, json_normalize was amazing! That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As the source DataFrame I used:

```
   people
1  {'count': 10, 'distances': {'values': [1, 2, 3], 'unit': 'X1'}}
2  {'count': 20, 'distances': {'values': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'unit': 'X2'}}
3  {'count': 30, 'distances': {'values': [8, 9], 'unit': 'X3'}}'''
```

To do your task, run:

```
result = df.people.apply(lambda tt: pd.json_normalize(
    pd.io.json.loads(tt.replace("'", '\"'))).iloc[0])
```

Steps:

- replace single quotes with double quotes,
- convert this string to a JSON object,
- call *json_normalize* (the result is a DataFrame),
- take only the first row of it.

The result, for my source data, is:

```
   count distances.values distances.unit
1     10        [1, 2, 3]             X1
2     20     [4, 5, 6, 7]             X2
3     30           [8, 9]             X3
```

If you need, rename columns other than *count*, dropping the initial
*distances* and a dot.

## Edit

Now I suppose, that your source data is a *Series* containing dictionaries.

So I created it the following way:

```
p = [{'count': 10, 'distances': {'values': [1, 2, 3], 'unit': 'X1'}},
     {'count': 20, 'distances': {'values': [4, 5, 6, 7], 'unit': 'X2'}},
     {'count': 30, 'distances': {'values': [8, 9], 'unit': 'X3'}}]
people = pd.Series(p, index=range(1, len(p) + 1))
```

Then, to get the expected result, run:

```
result = pd.json_normalize(people)
```

Comment: Valdi_Bo, I was not able to execute your code. I tried replacing df.people with People since df. is not defined. The issue I was having was with an errror "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'".

Comment: In my test data the type of *people* column is **string**, not dictionary. You failed to provide this detail. Change the type of your data and my code should work.